# Does checkpointing with torch.save fail with hugging face -- if not what is the right way to checkpoint and load a hugging face (HF) model?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

Does torch.save work on hugging face models (I am using vit)? I assumed yes.

My error:

```
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 379, in save
    _save(obj, opened_zipfile, pickle_module, pickle_protocol)
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 499, in _save
    zip_file.write_record(name, storage.data_ptr(), num_bytes)
OSError: [Errno 116] Stale file handle
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/shared/rsaas/miranda9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_dist_maml_l2l.py", line 1815, in <module>
    main()
  File "/shared/rsaas/miranda9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_dist_maml_l2l.py", line 1748, in main
    train(args=args)
  File "/shared/rsaas/miranda9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_dist_maml_l2l.py", line 1795, in train
    meta_train_iterations_ala_l2l(args, args.agent, args.opt, args.scheduler)
  File "/home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/training/meta_training.py", line 213, in meta_train_iterations_ala_l2l
    log_train_val_stats(args, args.it, step_name, train_loss, train_acc, training=True)
  File "/home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/logging_uu/wandb_logging/supervised_learning.py", line 55, in log_train_val_stats
    _log_train_val_stats(args=args,
  File "/home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/logging_uu/wandb_logging/supervised_learning.py", line 113, in _log_train_val_stats
    save_for_supervised_learning(args, ckpt_filename='ckpt.pt')
  File "/home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/checkpointing_uu/supervised_learning.py", line 54, in save_for_supervised_learning
    torch.save({'training_mode': args.training_mode,
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 380, in save
    return
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 259, in __exit__
    self.file_like.write_end_of_file()
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at inline_container.cc:298] . unexpected pos 2736460544 vs 2736460432
```

my code:

```
        # - ckpt
        args_pickable: Namespace = uutils.make_args_pickable(args)
        # note not saving any objects, to make sure checkpoint is loadable later with no problems
        torch.save({'training_mode': args.training_mode,
                    'it': args.it,
                    'epoch_num': args.epoch_num,

                    # 'args': args_pickable,  # some versions of this might not have args!
                    # decided only to save the dict version to avoid this ckpt not working, make it args when loading
                    'args_dict': vars(args_pickable),  # some versions of this might not have args!

                    'model_state_dict': get_model_from_ddp(args.model).state_dict(),
                    'model_str': str(args.model),  # added later, to make it easier to check what optimizer was used
                    'model_hps': args.model_hps,
                    'model_option': args.model_option,

                    'opt_state_dict': args.opt.state_dict(),
                    'opt_str': str(args.opt),
                    'opt_hps': args.opt_hps,
                    'opt_option': args.opt_option,

                    'scheduler_str': str(args.scheduler),
                    'scheduler_state_dict': try_to_get_scheduler_state_dict(args.scheduler),
                    'scheduler_hps': args.scheduler_hps,
                    'scheduler_option': args.scheduler_option,
                    },
                   pickle_module=pickle,
                   f=args.log_root / ckpt_filename)
```

if this is not the right way to checkpoint hugging face (HF) models, what is?

---

cross: hf discussion forum: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/torch-save-with-hugging-face-models-fails/25034